# How to remove Ubuntu 12.10 from dual boot with Win 7?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uninstall

I have dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 7. I wanted to uninstall Ubuntu. So as per an answer for one of the related questions on this site I did the following:

1. Deleted the Ubuntu Partition through Windows.
2. As per the answer now I was supposed to boot Windows from USB & then do "repair startup".

But Windows could not find any problem hence nothing was done.
So when my laptop booted normally (i.e. from HDD) it was showing some error like `GRUB:/ unknown file system`. I dont remember the exact words but it was something like this.
Thus I couldn't boot windows neither Ubuntu. So again I had to install Ubuntu.

But now my question is how do I remove Ubuntu so that my laptop returns to the previous state of installing Ubuntu?

UPDATE: Seems that it wasnt on this site. My mistake :P .Here is the link http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Comment: Are you talking about this question (ie; did you follow the answers from here): [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: no unforunately I cannot find that question, but now reading the question given by you I understand that I did the operation in reverse order.
But still I am sure that, that answer also mentioned the wrong order. Thats why I followed it & got stuck.

Comment: Okay, I have flagged the question as duplicate of the given link. You should follow the answers given there and if it doesn't work for you, then edit this question with your results and flag to get it reopened (in case this question gets closed as a duplicate by that time).

Answer (score 2):

Boot into windows. Remove the ubuntu bootloader from inside windows by reinstalling bcd  - [easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) or [visualbcd](http://www.boyans.net/) is a good easy way - I'm more used to easybcd

Install easybcd (the community edition is free for personal use)

[image]

Select BCD Deployment, select your partition, and clicking on Install BCD and Write MBR. Its dead simple.

Reboot and make sure bcd loads, rather than grub. Delete the ubuntu partition with disk management and resize as you'd like it.