# How do i uninstall ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

Hey i want to dual boot ubuntu 13.04 and according to the installation guide you just choose install alongside windows. I have used ubuntu 12.04 for a while now and i have to reformat my windows 7 so i thought i would try to install ubuntu 13.04. 
My question is when you install ubuntu through wubi it is easy to uninstall but is it the same if i would uninstall ubuntu 13.04? 
or if not "is there a good uninstallation guide"?.

Comment: one of these should work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/281646/how-to-remove-ubuntu-12-10-from-dual-boot-with-win-7                       http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: hmm i read through them i am going to read them more in depth when my pc is done formating. If i understand it right you can either install osunstaller and unstall it that way or boot a livecd and choose unstall ubuntu. Now i am not good at reading guides at forums so i can be wrong but thx for the reply. If there is a step by step guide you know of i would be even happier for your help :)

Comment: You will have to do it another way than you did with wubi. But some guides on the subject are available on the site, you are not the first one to ask for it. Search for it on the site when you need it, since you don't need it now. The question you find now might not be viable when you want to remove Ubuntu, so search the site instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Ubuntu
Get an Ubuntu installation disk (liveDVD or liveUSB).

Insert the Ubuntu disk into your DVD drive. (or connect your liveUSB)

Make sure that your BIOS (boot order) is set to boot from a CD/USB before a hard drive.
Start or restart your computer. If you do not see the Ubuntu logo, please refer to BootFromCD.

Choose the Try Ubuntu option in order to check that your hardware (screen, keyboard, internet...) is correctly recognized by Ubuntu.

Backup your documents on an external disk or DVDs
When you are ready to install Ubuntu on your hard disk, click the Install Ubuntu button. The installation wizard will appear:

Selecting language
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349879126.png

Select your desired language and click Continue. The Preparing to install Ubuntu window appears.

Preparing to install Ubuntu
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349879926.png

Select the desired options. Click Continue. The Installation type window appears.

Installation type
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349879961.png

Several choices are available:

- If you want to install Ubuntu alongside you other systems (eg alongside Windows), select the Install Ubuntu alongside them.
- If you want to install Ubuntu over your entire hard drive, select Erase disk and install Ubuntu, then select the hard drive that you want to install Ubuntu. Warning: this will erase all data and systems that are currently on the disk.
- If you want to manually setup your partitioning scheme, , select the Something else option. You will find further advice on the DiskSpace page.

Click Install now. From this point, the installation cannot be cancelled. Few additional parameters need to be setup. The Where are you? window appears.

Where are you?
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349881173.png

Select the location closest to your location. Click Continue. The Keyboard layout window appears.

Keyboard layout
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349880847.png

Select the correct keyboard layout. Click Continue. The Who are you? window appears.

Who are you?
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349881198.png

When the installation wizard finishes, the Installation complete window appears.

Installation complete
install-step8.png

Click Restart now to restart your computer. Ubuntu is now installed.

Comment: My question is not how to install ubuntu 13.04 but how to "uninstall" it. But you helped me get this step explained that well and i think others might find it useful to:). I would approve an explanation  on how to uninstall ubuntu in the same way you explained how to install it:)

Answer (score 0):

yes the installation for Ubuntu 13.04 is also simple but wubi doesn't support in windows 7 so try installating it from a dvd/ usb drive .
1. unistall the previous ubuntu by deleting the partition u have made for ubuntu 
2. next insert any windows 7 bootable dvd and go to command prompt and type these commands there:
  bootrec.exe /fixmbr
3. next install the new ubuntu 13.04

if u found this answer helpful mark my answer as appropriate one

Comment: Thank for your reply. I know how to uninstall ubuntu when using wubi and according to ubuntu13.04 install guide i know how to install it alongside windows 7. But i want to be able to uninstall ubuntu 13.04 if i want or if i have to for some reason. Is it as easy as wubi when installing alongside windows? or will i have to uninstall in another way? If possible i prefere step by step guides.