# Can't access recovery mode, for dual booting comp, by holding shift

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, wubi, password-recovery

I used Wubi to install Ubuntu without a CD or USB. 
I cannot get my (username - password) combination to work even though I'm 100% sure I typed them in correctly when installing via Wubi. I read this password-non-recognition is a common issue with wubi and that I can find out my username and password through some command line thing within recovery mode. I have a dual-booted setup with windows 7 and Ubuntu in separate partitions. So when trying to access recovery mode I hold down the left-shift-key as soon as a press enter when choosing "ubuntu" as my operating system. When I do this, nothing happens and I load in to the login screen (after around 15 seconds).

I cannot get to the screen that lets my choose to boot in recovery mode (I think this screen is called GRUB?)  I read that "Boot-Repair" might somehow fix this issue, but I do not have access to a USB or CD that I can use to install "Boot-Repair."

Any ideas where I can go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the *left Shift* key as your laptop starts to boot. if that doesn't display the menu try  pressing the *Esc key* repeatedly. On a different note, I had the same issue in  the  past and ended up re-installing ubuntu by deleting it via windows and then using Universal USB Installer [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).. to boot up from a flash drive...

Comment: I have tried holding down the left-shift key and also tried pressing the esc key repeatedly.
Also, I do not have access to a flash drive (hence why I'm using Wubi).

Comment: read this ==>> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: Yes, you cant use flash drive,because you are locked out of the system. What I did - I started windows hard deleted ubuntu OS and then used the flash drive "method" for a fresh re-install. deleting Ubuntu is done by doing the following http://askubuntu.com/questions/281646/how-to-remove-ubuntu-12-10-from-dual-boot-with-win-7  . fyi, I am not saying delete your OS , that is just what I did after spending hours following posts and other resources ;]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Esc+F12 might also works for few Pcs, you can try that as well.

Otherwise just hold Left shift+Esc you will go to grub. There, you just have to hold Ctrl+Alt+Del to get to boot menu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).